# When will scanf append '\0' to user input?

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf

I understand that `scanf("%s",arr);` will automatically append `'\0'` to the user input. But I thought that it was limited only to this. However even `scanf("%[^\n]",arr);` also appends a '\0'.(I know this scans all characters until a newline is reached). In this case will `'\0'` be appended after `'\n'` or before `'\n'`. Also how do we figure out when and when not `'\0'` will be appended? How do we scan many characters to just form a character array and not a string?

Comment: It would be rather pointess if the string obtaind via `scanf` was not terminated by a `'\0'`.

Comment: Rule of Thumb: standard library functions handling strings will always append the null character. The only exception is `strncpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also how do we figure out when and when not '\0' will be appended?

As `scanf` is a standard function, we figure that out from the C standard. From [C11 draft 7.21.6.2p12](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12l):

> s
>    ... the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the sequence and a terminating null character, which will be added automatically. ...
>
> [
>   ...  the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the sequence and a terminating null character, which will be added automatically. ...

There is also nicer looking and commonly used for fast reference the  [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) site.

I strongly suggest you never, ever use `%s` and `%[` without a number specifying the "maximum field width" (unless you know you can use it). Always use `%<number>s` and `%<number>[`, to limit the number of character read and prevent overflow. So always:

```
char arr[20];
scanf("%19s", arr);
```

`scanf` is very unsafe function in that manner, it's easy to do stack overflow when reading strings.

> How do we scan many characters to just form a character array and not a string?

I think you want:

> size_t fread(void * restrict ptr,
>                 size_t size, size_t nmemb,
>                 FILE * restrict stream);
>
> The fread function reads, into the array pointed to by ptr, up to nmemb elements whose size is specified by size, from the stream pointed to by stream.

It will read `nmemb` elements of size `size` to the memory pointed to by `ptr`. So just:

```
 char character_array[20];
 size_t number_of_chcaracter_read = fread(character_array, 20, 1, stdin);
```

It will not append the terminating null byte to the `character_array`.